# Display a popup from backend in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I would like to display a popup in VB.Net when a button is clicked. I do not want to have the modalpopupextender codes to be on the aspx file. How do I code in the backend for a new modalpopupextender, a panel and its elements and display the popup when the button is clicked?

Comment: Why don't you want to have the extender on aspx? You could make it `Visible` when the button was clicked.

Comment: I would like to have some dynamic content in the panel that will act as modal window.

Comment: You could add the dynamic content but the popup itself doesn't need to be created dynamically.

Comment: I have brought up a popup. From that window, I trigger an event from a button to bring another popup with some dynamic content. I tried to handle the click event. the click event is not working and I get the popup without any content. Could you tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

you can create the js function that creates a popup at the front and then call that function using this function on VB

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "YourPopupFunction", "YourPopupFunction();", true);